# Installed a python library but (running it from IDLE) whenever i try to import it it returns a ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pyenchant

Python noobie here, so im trying to install the "PyEnchant" library for a program. I followed all the installation steps, with pip install pyencahnt returning:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyenchant in c:\users\micha\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (3.0.1)
```

Then, when I try to do import enchant from the python shell I still get the error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\micha\Desktop\PythonStuff\Wordhunt.py", line 7, in 
    import enchant
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'enchant'

> > >

What do I do to fix this?

Comment: what version of python do you have installed on your machine? from looking at your pip install, your enchant module needs python version 3.8. so do a "python --version" on command line and see your python version you are using.

Comment: I did that and it returned "Python 3.8.2", so what would the issue be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out
I opened the command prompt, navigated to my Scripts folder

```
C:\Users\micha>cd "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"
```

I THEN used pip install pyenchant and now it works